# Multiple line text labels plotly

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I have some bar charts with some longer labels and I'd like to stack the labels with multiple lines of text.

So "A very long sentence that needs broken up" appears as

A very long
sentence that needs
broken up.

I'd like to make the change ideally in plotly and not in my pandas dataframe.  But if that is the easier way to do that please let me know.  Here is an MRE.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x1 = ['A very long sentence that needs broken up', 'Regular Length', "Cory", "Dave"]

y1 = [20, 30, 25, 40]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x1, y=y1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you can do this by adding a `<br>` element in the input text. One more way is to hardset the `tickwidth` using

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = {
    'tickwidth' : %number in px
    }
)
```

[image: The sample output in 2 lines]

You can find the documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-tickwidth)

Alternate way is to check the `ticklen` or `tickformat` parameters also

Comment: Thank you very much!  What px did you put in for the example above?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of plotly, you can control the labels with HTML, so you can do this with the following code.

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='array',
                tickvals=[0,1,2,3],
                ticktext=['A very long sentence</br></br> that needs broken up', 'Regular Length', "Cory", "Dave"])
```

Comment: Not sure this will work for me since I have multiple plots in a dropdown menu.  Thanks though