# Plotly : multi line alignment for long axis labels

Tags: python, plotly

How do we align the xaxes labels (that are very loong) to be shown in multiple lines.

Below is an example in excel.

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in plotly (using `ticklen`, `tickwidth`), but it doesnt mention it in multiple lines.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple line text labels plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546691/multiple-line-text-labels-plotly)